# Customizing REST API response

Tags: java, rest, jackson2

I want to send the data in the below format, as the front end expects that data to be in this format

```
[
     [
      {
        "data": [
          [
            "x1-m1",
            128650.3
          ],
          [
            "x2-m2",
            19589.033
          ]
        ]

      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "data": [
          [
            "x1-m1",
            128640.3
          ],
          [
            "x2-m2",
            19559.033
          ]
        ]

      }
    ]  
]
```

Below is what I tried

```
public class FilterFluorescence {

    private String filter;
    private double fluorescence;

    public FilterFluorescence() {
    }

    public FilterFluorescence(String filter, double fluorescence) {
        this.filter = filter;
        this.fluorescence = fluorescence;
    }

    public String getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }
    public void setFilter(String filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }
    public double getFluorescence() {
        return fluorescence;
    }
    public void setFluorescence(double fluorescence) {
        this.fluorescence = fluorescence;
    }   
}
```

WellFilterFluorescence

```
public class WellFilterFluorescence {

    List<FilterFluorescence> data;

    public List<FilterFluorescence> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<FilterFluorescence> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

PlateFilterFluorescence

```
public class PlateFilterFluorescence {

    private List<WellFilterFluorescence> wellFilterFluorescence;

    public List<WellFilterFluorescence> getWellFilterFluorescence() {
        return wellFilterFluorescence;
    }

    public void setWellFilterFluorescence(List<WellFilterFluorescence> wellFilterFluorescence) {
        this.wellFilterFluorescence = wellFilterFluorescence;
    }

}
```

RawDataCurve

```
public class RawDataCurve {

    private List<PlateFilterFluorescence> plateFilterFluorescence;

    public void setPlateFilterFluorescence(List<PlateFilterFluorescence> plateFilterFluorescence ) {
        this.plateFilterFluorescence = plateFilterFluorescence;
    }

    public List<PlateFilterFluorescence> getPlateFilterFluorescence() {
        return this.plateFilterFluorescence;
    }

}
```

And I'm sending a `List<RawDataCurve>` as the API response, which looks like as below

```
[
  {
    "plateFilterFluorescence": [
      {
        "wellFilterFluorescence": [
          {
            "data": [
              {
                "filter": "X1_M1",
                "fluorescence": 118303.515625
              },
              {
                "filter": "X4_M4",
                "fluorescence": 144837.296875
              }
            ]
          }
         ]
        }
       ]
     },
    {
    "plateFilterFluorescence": [
      {
        "wellFilterFluorescence": [
          {
            "data": [
              {
                "filter": "X1_M1",
                "fluorescence": 118303.515625
              },
              {
                "filter": "X4_M4",
                "fluorescence": 144837.296875
              }
            ]
          }
         ]
        }
       ]
     }
]
```

How can I remove the attribute names in the converted JSON produced by Jackson, and what should be the better way to do this? My current approach looks to be messy.

Answer (score 0):

As per your desire expectations -

`{`

`"data": [["x1-m1",128650.3],["x2-m2", 19589.033]],....`

`}`

I would suggest not to repeat the data node object and only have the repeated content inside it, and you can structure like this -

`{`

`"data": [
      [
        "x1-m1",
        128650.3
      ],
      [
        "x2-m2",
        19589.033
      ],
      [
        "x3-m3",
        12589.011
      ],
       ....., ... 
    ]`

`}`

Form your object as below -

```
public class RawDataCurve {

List<FilterFluorescence> data;

    public List<FilterFluorescence> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<FilterFluorescence> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Comment: But still it will have below structure {
                "filter": "X1_M1",
                "fluorescence": 118303.515625
              }

Comment: It would look like - { data : [ "filter": "X1_M1", "fluorescence": 118303.515625 ], [ "filter": "X2_M2", "fluorescence": 108303.515625 ], ... }